# Cloudify chef plugin relationship operation

Tags: cloudify

As I know Cloudify's Chef Plugin allow to define operation in keyword:

> runlists:

with default prefixs are:

> cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle,
>   cloudify.interfaces.relationship_lifecycle

So now I want to run relationship's operations such as

> cloudify.interfaces.relationship_lifecycle.preconfigure

as below

> runlists:
>   ----preconfigure: scripts/pre.sh

then I don't know which interface will be run? Source interface or target?
And if I want to specify to run target interface, how can i do that?

Comment: Removing the Chef tag as this seems to be entirely about Cloudify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the chef plugin all relationship operations use the source interface.

If you want to specify to run on the target interface, you would need to add a new [relationship type](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-chef-plugin/blob/1.3.1/plugin.yaml#L289) to the plugin with the target interface defined. However, that would only work if the target interface represents a node that is contained on a VM that has chef.